# Publish app wall share option

Tags: facebook, publish

I have read a guide for publish link to my wall or my fan page. Here is the guide: net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/wrangling-with-the-facebook-graph-api/

This is my application test:

http://www.onlyimagination.com/mytest/source/

The application works, but i don't want GENERATE the link manually, i want only SHARE.

This is the [screenshot](http://onlyimagination.com/1.png) of the publish of this app

Instead I would just put the link and my application AUTOMATICALLY extracts all the links like this sharing of information here in this [screenshot](http://onlyimagination.com/2.png).

Answer (score 1):

The info presented in the 2nd screenshot is just the info of the picture that facebook has.

In order to tell facebook how to present your links you need to use [the Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) (you can also use the [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) docs).
With this protocol you define properties which facebook knows how to extract, such as title, type, image and more.

This means that the response for every link you want people to share on facebook should contain the og meta tags.

---

## Edit

Sorry, did not think about adding this before:

You can use the [Debugger tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see how facebook "sees" urls.
You see, what happens when a user shares a link is that facebook has a program that send a request for the shared link, it then parses the response and search for specific tags to extract the data which is then presented to the user.
For example, try the [Debugger for google.com](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.google.com) and see what info was extracted, then try to share it and see that it uses the same info.

Also, at the bottom of the Debugger result, there's a link ***Scraped URL**: See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL* if you click that you see the actual response.

Hope this clarifies it.

---

## 2nd Edit

I don't know how you publish your posts in your app (next time it could be easier if you just add the code you use), but it doesn't matter how you publish it (js sdk or from the server side) you always have two options:

- Post a link that has the og meta tags in it, those will tell facebook how to display the link
- Add the *link*, *picture*, *name*, *caption* and *description* fields when posting [(js sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) for client and [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) for server)

Comment: Do you know Postcron.com? if you look in too and insert a link in the box the app automaticly get the info... how?

Comment: I know what you mean, but i want insert to my app